# angular/rxjs- deep copying data sent as string

Tags: javascript, angular

```
{
  single: {
   userId: {
    messages: Message[],
  },
  group: {
    groupId: {
      messages: Message[],
    },
  },
  notifications: {
    id: data,
  }
}
```

that data is being sent through JSON.stringify(objAbove). the problem I am having is with `JSON.parse(objAbove)` if there is an object within `messages` property it is not there.

```js
    1   private _subToStoredMessages(): Observable<void> {
    2     return this.socket.fromEvent('ask-messages').pipe(
    3       map((msgs: string): void => {
    4         console.log('--->', msgs); // all information is there
   10         this.jsonConverter(msgs)
   11           .then(res => {
   12             console.log('res from json converter', res);
   13             this.handleStoredMessages(res);
   14           })
   15           .catch(err => {
   16             console.log(err);
   17           });
   18       }),
   19     );
   20   }
   21
   22   private async jsonConverter(json: string): Promise<any> {
   23     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   24       console.log('json', JSON.parse(json)); // anything in messages property is missing
   25       resolve(JSON.parse(json));
   26       reject({ problem: 'error', id: JSON.parse(json) });
   27     });
   28   }
```

### UPDATE:

image of my console log showing the issue:
[image]

If there is an array with 5 messages in it, then only 3 messages will show, if there is an array with only 1 message in there then it won't be there. I have no clue what's going on and I've spent about 6 hours now on it. any help would be very *VERY* appreciated. thank you

Comment: Could you clarify this "if there is an object within messages property it is not there"?

Comment: added photo of my console log to better show

Comment: What will happen if you try to run `JSON.parse(jsonText)` in browser console?

Comment: your question is not clear. explain it clearly. what exactly is your prob?

Comment: I don't find any bug in the code you have shown.

Comment: can you setup a stackblitz?